# Reasoning through a program in Prolog

Tags: debugging, prolog

I am attempting a past paper question for a Prolog exam. I drew a 'tree' for how I believed Prolog ought to behave given the program and a certain goal. However, Prolog does not behave as I expected, and given a query for which I believed it would return 'true', it actually returned 'false'.

Here is my program:

```
sum(Term,N) :- Term = 0, N = 0.
sum(Term,N) :- Term = f(M,Subterm), number(M), sum(Subterm,N-M).
```

My query and search tree are as follows (goals are bracketed and in bold):

**[ sum(f(1,0),1) ]**

Using Rule 1, let Term = 0, N = 0, tries to unify **[ 1 = 0, 1 = 0 ]** fail.

Redo: using Rule 2, let Term = f(1,0), N=1 **[ f(1,0) = f(M,Subterm), number(M), sum(Subterm,1-1) ]**

Unifying, let M=1 and Subterm=0 **[ number(1), sum(0,0) ]**

Using Rule 1, this should succeed. However (SWI) Prolog says 'false'.

If someone can point out to me why my reasoning is flawed (and how I can learn from this in future), I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more accurate, the first rule tries to unify `f(1,0) = 0` and `1 = 0`, which of course fails.

Analysis of rule 2 is also incorrect. Partly, it's because Prolog **does not** evaluate arithmetic expressions inline. The term `N-M` is just a term (short-hand for `'-'(N, M)`. It does not result in `M` being subtracted from `M` unless the evaluation is done explicitly via `is/2` or an arithmetic comparison (e.g., `=:=/2`, `=</2`, etc).

The analysis of rule 2 would go as follows. Step 5 is where your logic breaks down due to the above.

1. Call `sum(f(1,0), 1)` results in `Term = f(1,0)` and `N = 1`.
2. In rule 2, `Term = f(M, Subterm)` becomes `f(1,0) = f(M, Subterm)` which results in `M = 1` and `Subterm = 0`.
3. `number(N)` becomes `number(1)` and succeeds (since 1 is a number)
4. The call `sum(Subterm, N-M)` becomes `sum(0, 1-1)`.
5. Prolog matches `sum(0, 1-1)` with the head of rule 1 `sum(Term, N) :- Term = 0, N = 0.`, but it fails because `1-1 = 0` (which is the same as `'-'(1, 1) = 0` unification fails.
6. Prolog matches `sum(0, 1-1)` with the head of rule 2, and unifies `Term = 0` and `N = 1-1` (or `N = '-'(1, 1)`).
7. `Term = f(M, Subterm)` becomes `0 = f(M, Subterm)` which fails because `0` cannot match the term `f(M, Subterm)`.
8. No more rules to attempt, so the predicate call fails.

The easy fix here is a common, basic Prolog pattern to use a new variable to evaluate the expression explicitly:

```
sum(Term,N) :-
    Term = f(M,Subterm),
    number(M),
    R is N - M,
    sum(Subterm, R).
```

You can also tidy up the code quite a bit by unifying in the heads of the clauses. So the clauses could be rewritten:

```
sum(0, 0).
sum(f(M, Subterm), N) :-
    number(N),
    R is N - M,
    sum(Subterm, R).
```

---

*EDIT*: My answer is intended to guide you through a walk through of your existing logic. Other than correcting the misunderstanding regarding expression evaluation, I did not analyze your solution for overall correctness.

Answer (score 4):

Since your program is almost a pure<sup>1</sup> one, you can locate the error in a systematic manner without using a debugger. The idea is to generalize your program by removing goals, one-by-one.  I came up with the following pure generalization which I obtained by "commenting" out some goals like so:

```
:- op(950, fy, *).
*(_).

sum(Term,N) :-
   Term = 0,
   N = 0.
sum(Term,N) :-
   * Term = f(M,Subterm),
   * number(M),
   sum(Subterm,N-M).

?- sum(Term, N).
   Term = 0, N = 0
;  false.
```

Also the query above is more general than yours. This is a very useful technique in Prolog: Instead of thinking about concrete solutions, we
first let Prolog do all the work for us.

The answer was quite clear: There is exactly one solution to this relation, even if the relation is now generalized.

So the problem must be somewhere in the remaining visible part. Actually, it's the `-`. Why not write instead:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

sum(0, 0).
sum(Term, N0) :-
   Term = f(M, Subterm),
   N0 #= M+N1,
   sum(Subterm, N1).
```

I find that program much easier to understand. If I read a name `sum`, I immediately look for a corresponding `+`. Of course, if you insist, you could write `N0-M #= N1` instead. It would be exactly the same, except that this requires a bit more thinking.

---

<sub>**Fine print you don't need to read**</sub>

1) Your original program used `number/1` which is not pure. But since the problem persisted by removing it, it did not harm our reasoning.

Comment: *If I read a name sum, I immediately look for a corresponding +.* Boom! :)